# Javascript right encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, urlencode, url-encoding

I have this:

```
var passwordpolicies = {
    shouldbecomplex: shouldbecomplex,
    shouldnotbeusername: shouldnotbeusername,
    shouldnotincludeusercharacters: shouldnotincudeusercharacters,
    passwordminage: passwordminage,
    passwordmaxage: passwordmaxage,
    passwordminlength: passwordminlength,
    passwordmaxlength: passwordmaxlength,
    passwordchronic: passwordchronic
};

var iprange = {
    enableiprange: enableiprange,
    iplist: ipList
};
```

But I need to get exactly this: How can I do this?

> iprange=%7B%22enableiprange%22%3Atrue%2C%22iplist%22%3A%5B%22155.56.68.217%22%2C%22156.187.50.4%22%5D%7D&passwordpolicies=%7B%22shouldbecomplex%22%3Atrue%2C%22shouldnotbeusername%22%3Afalse%2C%22shouldnotincludeusercharacters%22%3Afalse%2C%22passwordminage%22%3A-1%2C%22passwordmaxage%22%3A-1%2C%22passwordminlength%22%3A6%2C%22passwordmaxlength%22%3A-1%2C%22passwordchronic%22%3A-1%7D

For sure I have the right values in the variables inside the objects.

I am not that familiar with encoding, and tried
**encodeURIComponent** and **jQuery.param** but didn't succeeded.

When doing: `encodeURIComponent({iprange, passwordpolicies})`
I get this:

> %5Bobject%20Object%5D

And when doing: `jQuery.param( {iprange, passwordpolicies} )`
I get this:

> iprange%5Benableiprange%5D=false&iprange%5Biplist%5D%5B%5D=155.56.68.217&iprange%5Biplist%5D%5B%5D=156.187.50.4&passwordpolicies%5Bshouldbecomplex%5D=true&passwordpolicies%5Bshouldnotbeusername%5D=false&passwordpolicies%5Bshouldnotincludeusercharacters%5D=false&passwordpolicies%5Bpasswordminage%5D=&passwordpolicies%5Bpasswordmaxage%5D=&passwordpolicies%5Bpasswordminlength%5D=6&passwordpolicies%5Bpasswordmaxlength%5D=&passwordpolicies%5Bpasswordchronic%5D=

When doing this:
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myObj))
I get this:

> %7B%22iprange%22%3A%7B%22enableiprange%22%3Afalse%2C%22iplist%22%3A%5B%22155.56.68.217%22%2C%22156.187.50.4%22%5D%7D%2C%22passwordpolicies%22%3A%7B%22shouldbecomplex%22%3Atrue%2C%22shouldnotbeusername%22%3Afalse%2C%22shouldnotincludeusercharacters%22%3Afalse%2C%22passwordminage%22%3A%22%22%2C%22passwordmaxage%22%3A%22%22%2C%22passwordminlength%22%3A%226%22%2C%22passwordmaxlength%22%3A%22%22%2C%22passwordchronic%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D

Comment: You need to show us your attempt before we can tell you what is wrong with it

Comment: `JSON.stringify()`+ `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: @Quentin: Please see my edit.

Comment: While typing you've found it out yourself^^ Just add it as an answer instead of an edit to "close" the question properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is to use `JSON.stringify()` and `encodeURIComponent()` like Andreas proposed.

```
"iprange=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(iprange)) + "&passwordpolicies=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(passwordpolicies));
```